# caption position with subfloat command of float package

Tags: subfloats

I have some code that used to work correctly on some other machine, but I currently have an issue with subfloat captions: They appear next to the image (on the left side) instead of below.
Here is a minimal exemple:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[subcap 1]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
\subfloat[subcap 2]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
\caption{caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And here is the result:

[image: subcaption_bug]

I managed to get the result I want using the subcaption package, with the following syntax:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{subcap 1}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

With subfig, it works as expected.
But I have a very big document, with other commands that are specific to subcaption. I don't want to have to change everything if I can help it...
I'm getting confused between all different subfloat packages. I only find information on subfig or subcaption.

What can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SX! Your code is fine. Just add the required package (`subcaption` or `subfig`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Actually, yes, I forgot to mention I was using subcaption in my doc.
But when I add it to the above exemple, it produces the same result.
Subfig works indeed, but I would still have to change a lot of stuff, and I am using hyperref, I read they are not compatible. I will give it a try though.
But I would like to understand why it stopped working correctly with subcaption.

Comment: Here (https://imgur.com/cDebw4v) is what I got after adding the `subcaption` package. The output seems ok. I am not sure but maybe there are some other issues. You may try to reproduce the error and show here.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question to include the output.
I found an acceptable solution by using subfig, and replacing calls such as `\begin{subfigure}` by `\begin{minipage}`.
I have a document very similar to what I expect with mininal changes to the code.
But still, I would be interested to understand where my problem comes from.

I just installed the latest version of MikTeX, and I am using a recent install of TexMaker as well, which downloads package automatically. If it can help...

Comment: You are right, although the documentation for the `subcaption` package tells us that it provides a command `\subfloat` for compatibility reasons that should behave exactly like the macro with the same name from the `subfig` package, as of TeXLive 2021, this seems not to work. With older installations, however, it works. I don't exactly know why this is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the `subfigure` package is deprecated and its successor, the `subfig` package, was last updated in 2005.

Therefore, I suggest you just use the preferred syntax for the `subcaption` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{subcap 1}{\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{subcap 2}{\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
\caption{caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.
I didn't know the subcaptionbox command.
I wonder why they changed the bracket style, but at least, I can get my code running with minimal changes.